# How to use TLS for secure communication in clusters ？

Tags: cluster-computing, tls1.3

I'm implementing secure communication between clusters. However, there is very little information on this. It is only known that TLS can be used as a protocol for encrypted communication. But how do you set up a certificate between leader and the follower?

My first iead is, The leader holds the private key and then distributes the public key to the follower. Is this thinking correct?
The second idea is to issue a key pair to each server and then send the certificate to the leader.
Is there any such information on using TLS for secure communication in clusters?